# How to pass a variable from MainActivity to ListAdapter using intend

Tags: java, android-studio, kotlin

I want to share data between MainActivity to ListAdapter. The problem is that intend is shown as "unresolved reference". The main problem is that I can't transfer "master" variable from MainActivity to ListAdapter, I really need the variable because I need to encrypt my passwords in my app.

List adapter

```
package com.example.roomapp.fragments.list
import android.app.PendingIntent.getActivity
import android.content.ContentValues.TAG
import android.content.Context
import android.content.Intent
import android.view.LayoutInflater
import android.view.View
import android.view.ViewGroup
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
import com.example.roomapp.AESKnowledgeFcatory.encrypt
import com.example.roomapp.R
import com.example.roomapp.data.User
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.custom_row.view.*
import android.content.SharedPreferences
import com.example.roomapp.HashUtils.sha256
import com.example.roomapp.MainActivity
import android.content.Intent.getIntent

import android.os.Bundle
import android.util.Log
import android.widget.Toast


class ListAdapter(): RecyclerView.Adapter<ListAdapter.MyViewHolder>() {


    private var userList = emptyList<User>()


    class MyViewHolder(itemView: View): RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView) {}

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): MyViewHolder {

        return MyViewHolder(LayoutInflater.from(parent.context).inflate(R.layout.custom_row, parent, false))

    }

    override fun getItemCount(): Int {
       return userList.size
    }


    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: MyViewHolder, position: Int) {


        val extras = getIntent().extras
        if(extras!=null)
        {
            val value = extras.getString("key")
        }

        val currentItem = userList[position]
        holder.itemView.id_txt.text = currentItem.id.toString()
        holder.itemView.firstName_txt.text = currentItem.firstName
        holder.itemView.lastName_txt.text = encrypt(currentItem.lastName,sha256(i+currentItem.salt.toString()))
        holder.itemView.salt_txt.text = currentItem.salt
    }

    fun setData(user: List<User>){
        this.userList = user
        notifyDataSetChanged()
    }
}
```

MainActivity

```
package com.example.roomapp

import android.content.Intent
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import android.os.Bundle
import android.view.View
import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment
import androidx.navigation.findNavController
import androidx.navigation.ui.setupActionBarWithNavController
import com.example.roomapp.AESKnowledgeFcatory.decrypt
import com.example.roomapp.HashUtils.sha256
import com.example.roomapp.fragments.add.AddFragment
import com.example.roomapp.fragments.list.ListAdapter
import com.example.roomapp.fragments.list.ListFragment
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.activitycreate.*
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.activitylogin.*
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.custom_row.*
import kotlin.properties.ReadOnlyProperty
import kotlin.reflect.KProperty

class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    var master: String = "0"
    var checkLogin2: String = ""
    var lf_ch = false


    fun createMaster(v:View){
        this.master = this.editmasterpass.text.toString()

        val sharedPref = this.getPreferences(MODE_PRIVATE) ?:return
        with (sharedPref.edit()){
            putString("cheie",sha256(master))
            commit()
        }

        val sharedPref2 = this.getPreferences(MODE_PRIVATE) ?: return
        val defaultValue = sharedPref2.getString("cheie", "ABA")
        System.out.println(" Key value = " + defaultValue)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
    }

    fun checklogin(v: View)
    {
        this.checkLogin2 = this.editTextTextPassword.text.toString()
        val castoras = this.getPreferences(MODE_PRIVATE)
        val defaultValue2 = castoras.getString("cheie", "ABA")
        if(sha256(this.checkLogin2)==defaultValue2.toString())
        {

            val value: String = this.master // or just your string
            val intent = Intent(this, ListAdapter::class.java)
            intent.putExtra("value", value)
            startActivity(intent)


            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
        }
        else {
            textView3.text="Incorrect Password"
        }

    }


    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

        val castoras = this.getPreferences(MODE_PRIVATE)
        val defaultValue2 = castoras.getString("cheie", "key not found")

        System.out.println("Abracanabra= "+defaultValue2.toString())

        if ((defaultValue2.toString())=="key not found") {
            setContentView(R.layout.activitycreate)
        }
        else {
            setContentView((R.layout.activitylogin))
        }




    }


    override fun onSupportNavigateUp(): Boolean {
        val navController = findNavController(R.id.fragment)
        return navController.navigateUp() || super.onSupportNavigateUp()
    }



}
```

Comment: A ListAdapter isn't an Activity. It doesn't make sense to call `startActivity` with it. Why don't you just make a String property in the ListAdapter that the Activity can set? You only need Intents for communicating between distinct Activities/Services.

Answer (score 0):

That is because you are trying to call startActivity with the ListAdapter as the class, instead of another activity or fragment.

See [docu](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/starting-activity)